# How to fix a Veracode warning: "Use of Wrong Operator in String Comparison (CWE ID 597)"

Tags: string, veracode

Following a Veracode static scan, there is a warning of "Use of Wrong Operator in String Comparison (CWE ID 597)"

For the following code:

```
if (uid != null && uid != "") {
    // LOG.info("Inside deleteUser of Active directory");
    // HearsayLogger.message(HearsayLogger.TYPE_INFO, CLASSNAME, METHODNAME, "Inside deleteUser of Active directory");
}
```

How can I fix the warning?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the error message, this means that the wrong operator is used for a string comparison!

[CWE-597](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/597.html) gives you more information about the error and what to do. All of the Veracode warnings have a similar page that explain what is happening and why.

For this - I think you should be using:

```
if (uid != null && !uid.equals(""))
```

The reason: "For Java objects, such as String objects, the "==" and "!=" operators compare object references, not object values."